# Translating Imogen (an intuitionistic theorem prover for FOL) into a Prolog prover?

Tags: prolog

[imogen](https://github.com/seanmcl/imogen) is Sean McLaughlin's intuitionistic theorem prover in Standard ML
It would maybe interesting both for Logicians and Prolog programmers to translate imogen in Prolog, to compare this translation and to get maybe a better understanding of this very efficient intuitionistic prover.

Comment: seems a rather large code base... it's unlikely a direct translation to Prolog is either viable or convenient.

Comment: I once leafed through the 1994 paper [A PROLOG Interpreter for First-Order Intuitionistic Logic](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221135513_A_PROLOG_Interpreter_for_First-Order_Intuitionistic_Logic_Extended_Abstract) ... I have no idea how it relates to imogen but that paper alone seems complex.